# API request /v1/profile missing parameter identity_id

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have an phonegap project in which iOS platform is already integrated which is using the branch plugin and it is working fine. When i add the android platform in the same project then it is throwing an error from branch plugin.

When we start the app in android init() called properly after that it gives "API request /v1/profile missing parameter identity_id". I need your assistance for removing this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is branch plugin ?

Comment: It is cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking and here is the link -"https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking"